# Remove breathe artifacts from PPG-Signal with adaptive Filter

Tags: python, filter

I'm working on python project that consists on removing-breathe artifacts from ppg signal. I'm trying to apply either a frequency or time adaptive Filter (LMS) but it doesn't work for me.
The reference breathe signal ist sampled with 25 Hz and the PPG signal is sampled with 50 Hz.
The picture shows the raw PPG-Signal(blue) and I want to achieve the orange signal as output-signal.
[image: see picture here]

But as I tried to apply the lms algo I got a noisy signal and the artifacts couldn't be removed.
[image: see please picture below]

As I tried the frequency adaptive filter (the second code below) I got a signal like this.
[image: see please picture]

The codes are below.

```
def lms(self, x, d, N, mu):

    nIters = min(len(x), len(d)) - N
    u = np.zeros(N)
    w = np.zeros(N)
    e = np.zeros(nIters)
    for n in range(nIters):
        u[1:] = u[:-1]
        u[0] = x[n]
        e_n = d[n] - np.dot(u, w)
        w = w + mu * e_n * u
        e[n] = e_n

    return e

def freq_adap_filter(self, x, d, M, mu):

    num_block = min(len(x), len(d)) // M
    w_k = 0
    n_zeros = np.zeros(M)
    e = np.zeros(num_block * M)

    for n in range(num_block):

        # calculate filter output
        x_n = np.concatenate([n_zeros, x[n * M:(n + 1) * M]])  # size 2M
        x_k = fft(x_n)  # size 2M
        y_k = x_k * w_k  # size 2M filter output

        d_n = d[n * M:(n + 1) * M]  # size M
        y_n = ifft(y_k)  # size 2M
        y_n = y_n[M:2 * M]  # we take only the second half size M
        e_n = d_n - y_n  # size M
        e[n * M:(n + 1) * M] = e_n

        e_n = np.concatenate([n_zeros, e_n])  # size 2M
        e_k = fft(e_n)  # size 2M

        # update coefficient
        x_k_conj = x_k.conj()  # size 2M
        g_k = x_k_conj * e_k  # size 2M
        g_n = ifft(g_k)  # size 2M
        g_n = g_n[0:M]  # last Block deleted size M
        g_n = np.concatenate([g_n, n_zeros])  # size 2M
        w_k = w_k + mu * fft(g_n)  # size 2M

    return e
```

I would be very thankful if you could help me. I'm looking forward for your answers. Thank you.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Please explain it as detailed as possible and provide the expected result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have to remove the breathe artifacts from the raw signal (the blue signal) so what I'm expecting is a signal that looks like the orange signal in the picture above. I modified my question above and I added some explanation. I hope it could help you to understand my problem. Thank you.